# Convert image to array of floats and back in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I have code in Python that opens an image as grayscale, converts it to a numpy float array, perform a lot of mathematical operations on it, then normalizes and converts it to binary image (1 bit per pixel), saving it to disk again (PNG file).

Which .NET classes (preferrably) should I use to perform similar operations?

Below is a subset of my Python code:

```
im = Image.open(in_name)
a  = numpy.asarray(im.convert('L'), dtype=float)  ## implicit conversion to grayscale

## lots of element-wise arithmetical operations with 'a'
## and other similar-shaped arrays from other images

out_im = Image.fromarray(a.astype('uint8')).convert('1')
out_im.save(out_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this. You'll need XNA or DirectX in order to do either.

In XNA [Texture2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.aspx) objects contains the GetData and SetData methods which do what you want.

You can also use HLSL pixel shaders on a Texture2D to manipulate it. You can change your rendering target to render to another Texture2D which you save as an image file.

The second would be the fastest and most efficient, the first would be the easiest.